# How to filter the unreplied emails only in Outlook 2010?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I want to filter and view only the unreplied emails from me. So that, it would easier for me to ensure and reply all of them easily. Can you please suggest a way for this?

**Edited:**
Applied the solution provided by Sathiya:
[image]

Comment: Can you please post the solution so everyone can benefit.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see what this filter has got to do with replied messages. Maybe in your environment it does because of some side effect of the way you manage messages - but this certainly not a generic solution to the problem

Comment: Look here: http://superuser.com/questions/970558/how-to-search-for-unanswered-emails

Comment: Hi thims, The solution provided in that link works.

Answer (score 1):

The solution can be derived from the insights from [here](http://www.office-outlook.com/outlook-forum/index.php/m/445842/). I've performed the following steps for my Outlook 2010 32-bit and it works perfectly. I never investigated its compatibility with 64-bit Outlook, so please anyone who try it, share your experience. So let's begin:

1. Create a custom form by pasting the following code into text editor like Notepad:

   ```
   [Description]
   MessageClass=IPM.POST.CODETWO.LASTVERB
   DesignerRuntimeGuid={0006F020-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}
   CLSID={0006103A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}
   DisplayName=LastVerb
   Comment=Allows exposing last verb executed and last verb execution time in Outlook
   LargeIcon=postl.ico
   SmallIcon=posts.ico
   VersionMajor=1
   VersionMinor=0
   Hidden=1
   Owner=www.codetwo.com
   ComposeInFolder=1

   [Platforms]
   Platform2=NTx86
   Platform9=Win95

   [Platform.NTx86]
   CPU=ix86
   OSVersion=WinNT3.5

   [Platform.Win95]
   CPU=ix86
   OSVersion=Win95

   [Properties]
   Property01=LastVerbExecTime
   Property02=LastVerbExecType

   [Property.LastVerbExecTime]
   Type=64
   ;PropTag=PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTION_TIME
   NmidInteger=0x1082
   DisplayName=Last Verb Exec Time

   [Property.LastVerbExecType]
   Type=3
   ;PropTag=PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTED
   NmidInteger=0x1081
   DisplayName=Last Verb Exec Type

   [Verbs]
   Verb1=1

   [Verb.1]
   DisplayName=&Open
   Code=0
   Flags=0
   Attribs=2

   [Extensions]
   Extensions1=1

   [Extension.1]
   Type=30
   NmidPropset={00020D0C-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}
   NmidInteger=1
   Value=1002000000000000
   ```

   (credits to www.codetwo.com)
2. Save as a file **LastVerb.cfg** or any other name of your choice with **.cfg** extension. Take care about Notepad that may save you file like **LastVerb.cfg.txt** and Windows would hide **.txt** extension. Rename it manually in such a case.
3. Find location of Office custom forms on your system, something like **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\OfficeNN\FORMS\NNNN** or **C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\OfficeNN\FORMS\NNNN**. For example, on my system it is **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\FORMS\1033**.
4. Copy **LastVerb.cfg** into that location. On Windows Vista or 7 you will need to confirm administrative privileges (and of course, must have them) in order to put your file there.
5. Register this custom form with Outlook by going to menu **File**, then choose **Options**, **Advanced**, **Custom Forms**, **Manage Forms**, **Install...**, find your **LastVerb.cfg** file and click **OK** button then **Close** and again **OK**, **OK**.
6. Now you can use this custom form named **LastVerb** in several places in Outlook to set criteria for messages based on Replied / Forwarded status. For example, let's filter your Inbox view to see only unreplied (and unforwarded) messages. Go to Inbox folder.
7. Go to menu **View**, **View Settings**, then click **Filter...**, choose tab **Advanced**, click button **Field**
8. (You need to perform this step only for the first time.) In drop-down list click **Forms...**, then in top-left corner choose **Personal Forms** from the list, click on **LastVerb** item in the left panel and then button **Add ->**. Click **Close** button.
9. Click button **Field** again. This time, in the drop-down list find and click **LastVerb** then finally, **Last Verb Exec Type**. In the middle-bottom box titled **Condition**, choose **does not exist** then click **Add to list** button. Click buttons **OK** twice to confirm and close all dialog boxes. Enjoy unanswered-only view! Though I personally prefer using **Conditional Formatting...** in **View Settings** and paint unanswered messages into some really visible colour.

Phew, finally. Nine really sophisticated steps to achieve some really basic functionality - Microsoft ways, I guess?..

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try it and share my comments on the solution.